# Text cut off bottom of button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to add some formatting on a button for an application. The code for the button currently looks like this:

```css
.button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #4BBB44;
  border: 2px solid #2BB922;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```

I don't have the reputation to be able to post images, but the screenshot I wanted to post shows a green box with centered white text saying 'Search', but it is cut off at the bottom How do I stop the text being cut off at the bottom?

Comment: _"How do I stop the text being cut off at the bottom?"_ - remove the fixed `height`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove the `height` property, or adjust the `line-height` to vertically center the text in the button. example

```css
.button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #4BBB44;
  border: 2px solid #2BB922;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  /* add this */
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the height, if you remove the height declaration the text in the button will align properly:

```css
.button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #4BBB44;
  border: 2px solid #2BB922;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height:1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to set the `height` as `line-height`:

```css
.button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #4BBB44;
  border: 2px solid #2BB922;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    .button {
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #4BBB44;
  border: 2px solid #2BB922;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  /* add this */
  line-height: 0;
}
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
```